# Is there any possibility to add a module to a web service deployed on Tomcat without terminating the existing web service

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, osgi, mef

I have developed a web service using spring mvc and hibernate. Currently I couldn't find a solution to add a module to the running web service without terminating it. My intention is to develop the web service as modules and plug modules in runtime. In .Net the solution is developing the program using MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework) the DLL's. I developed some solutions using OSGI framework but I found some practicability issues existing. Please help me to find an applicable solution for the scenario.

Comment: You've already answered the question for yourself: OSGi. What were the "practicability issues"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

deepening of your plan. this is possible with OSGI by registering the new modules as Services and tracking all services in the Framework's service registry by using [ServiceTracker](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/OSGiServices/article.html#osgiservice_servicetracker)

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy the external module as a another app onto the container/server.  And leverage JNDI for resource sharing. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html